# Store lambda as a member using template arguments deduction

Tags: c++, lambda, auto, c++17, type-deduction

Previously, when *C++11* became available I tried to store a lambda as a class field using `auto` specifier and member initializers. It was an unsuccessfull attempt:

```
struct Y
{
    auto x = [] { ; };
};
```

Error:

> error: non-static data member declared with placeholder 'auto'

Despite of size of lambda (w/o lost of generality, with capture) is known at time of definition of a class member, it not allowed to use `auto` specifier. Why? Not too clear restriction.

Now [template argument deduction for class templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) available in GCC 7.0.0 trunk. And I tried to do it again:

```
template< typename F >
struct X
    : F
{
    using F::operator ();
    X(F && f) : F(static_cast< F && >(f)) { ; }
};

struct Y
{
    X x = [] { ; };
};
```

But I get an error:

> error: invalid use of template-name 'X' without an argument list

I suspect, that the implementation is partial or even maybe inconsistent. Will it allow me to achieve desired w/o type erasure (and dynamic allocation of a memory)?

Free non-member definition is allowed:

```
X x = [] { ; };
```

#### ADDITIONAL:

People asks what the problem I tried to solve? I need a terse syntax for in-class defined functors.

If I can write (following code is valid):

```
struct point_of_parabaloid // aggregate
{
    double x, y;
    double z = [&] { return x * x + y * y; }();
};

point_of_parabaloid p = {1.0, 2.0};
assert(p.z == 5.0);
```

Why can't I define an in-class lambda (say, for lazy evaluation of `z`)?

I don't need to capture something abnormal, just a class members (or `this`) as in `point_of_parabaloid` definition.

Comment: I can't think a single use case of your code. It makes no sense to me. You can't capture anything other than global variable. You can't reassign it.

Comment: You can store lambdas in a field of `std::function`. This is found in the header `<functional>`.

Comment: Give people a hammer and suddenly every problem looks like a nail. Seriously, why is it so hard to just use a *struct* with an `operator()` overload? You can't capture anything anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas 
I am ashamed =). I don't ever think about `struct` with `operator()`. But lambda is terse.

Comment: *What problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: @JoelCornett `std::function` is what I mean when mentioned *type erasure*.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Deduction rules - is a part of the proposal? I am surprised!

Comment: @GManNickG I need a terse syntax for in-class defined functors.

Comment: *"I suspect, that the implementation is partial or even maybe inconsistent."*, I think the reason `struct Y{ X x = []{}; };` is not allowed is that you can in parallel have another constructor, say, `Y() : x([](int){}) {}`, invalidating the deduction made for the provided in-class initializer

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki In such a case there should be a hard error on that default constructor's member initialization list, I sure.

Comment: the same happens when you try to in-class-initialize an array of unknown bounds, `struct Y { int t[] = {1, 2, 3}; };`

Comment: and I don't think the compiler should look at all constructors in order to deduce template parameters of that data member. imagine a header file without the definition of constructors

Comment: @NicolBolas I can capture already defined class members.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around it with `decltype` if the lambda is known before hand:

```
auto lambda = [](){};

struct C {
  decltype(lambda) member = lambda;
};
```

Not exactly pretty, but it works.

I think your template technique would work if rewritten as:

`auto x = X([](){});`

However, gcc-7 (snapshot) does not accept that either. I suspect that it is because it's still work in progress.

[just tested again with g++ 7 trunk built on 20161014, and then the above works]

You can work around it with a maker function

```
template <typename L>
struct X {
  L member;
};

template <typename T>
auto make_x(T t) { return X<T>{t}; }

auto x = make_x([](){});
```

Comment: I specifically need a data member.

Comment: My technique works. You can use [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SqOHEApeT37J43M3) for nightly build of latest GCC. You may delete the answer as irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to capture `this` outside a member function, in a class definition. To be precise, `double z = [&] { return x * x + y * y; }();` needs `this->x` and `this->y`.

You now get into a circular dependency: The type of the lambda depends on whats captured (`this`, which is a `point_of_parabaloid*`) but `point_of_parabaloid` depends on the type of its members including that very lambda.

This is a circular dependency in your design; the exact C++ constructs don't matter much. You can break it; `point_of_parabaloid*` only requires a forward declaration of `struct point_of_parabaloid;`. But breaking that circle isn't going to give you that terse syntax.

Comment: There is no problem with circular dependency for imaginary C++ compiler implementation, because size of any pointer (`this` inclusive) is known at compile time and equal to the size of `void *`. There is no problem, when we define simple function and use not-yet-even-declared data member symbol inside its body. Above code for `point_of_parabaloid` currently works fine - try it by yourself. Id est capture by reference works fine. The problem of non-captureless lambda in-class definition is just a size of capture inference at the point of definition. Such `auto` members must be at the end.

Comment: ...or to use already defined symbols only, or to use only references and pointers in captures.

Comment: @Orient: You'd need a special rule in the Standard for capturing pointers by value. Currently, you can capture anything by value, including things that have `sizeof T > sizeof (void*)`, so the captured types need to be fully defined. And yes, I think a conformant compiler could offer this as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your attempt in C++17, you can already do something similar in C++11.
As an example:

```
#include<utility>

template<typename F>
struct S {
    S(F f): f{f} {}
    F f;
};

template<typename F>
struct T: F {
    T(F f): F{f} {}
};

int main() {
    auto l = [](){ ; };

    S<decltype(l)> s{l};
    s.f();

    T<decltype(l)> t{l};
    t();
}
```

You can hide the ugly `decltype` behind a factory method if needed:

```
template<typename L>
static auto create(L l) {
       return S<decltype(l)>{l};
}
```

The limitation regarding this:

```
struct Y { auto x = [] { ; }; };
```

It is not because of the lambda. Instead, it's because of the `auto` placeholder. According with the standard, it cannot be used to declare non-static data members.
I guess the reason is that the type of a static data member is known at compile-time time (sooner or later you must put in an unique definition), while the type of a non-static data member could require to be solved at runtime. As an example, imagine an `if/else` statement where you use two different lambdas to initialize your object.

Comment: How to capture `this`?

Comment: @Orient In the `create` factory method, you can capture the class in the outer scope, that is the same to which the lambda is bound as a data member. It won't be able to access it's private members, I don't know if it's fine for you anyway.

Comment: @T.C. Is it for me, for Orient or for both of us?